# blogger dynamic views template showing images in the sidebar for posts

Tags: css, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

[image]
I just highlighted in yellow where there is a space for thumbnail images of blog posts.

I am sure there is some simple snippet css will help

Because i donot find a setting in blogger

When i looked at the html generated from the browser class="item hentry ... i donot see a thumbnail tag which has img.

Update: I tried the below css hack as well.

```
.hide-thumbnail .PopularPosts-thumbnail {display: block!important;}
```

There is no code, i followed the steps in blogger to bring the dynamic views
as mentioned here.
https://www.mayura4ever.com/2012/05/how-to-configure-your-blog-with-dynamic.html

Where i am missing

Comment: Hi, please add the related code snippets.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.sidebar .item.hentry .thumbnail{
display: block !important;
}

.sidebar .item.hentry.selected .thumbnail{
display: block !important;
}
```

This css fixes it.